Get-ItemProperty Extracting Data Installed Software & Location Help - Powershell
I'm quite a notice at Powershell. I'm a self taught fan been using it for a number of years, which I'm just making do, and expanding my portfolio of findings for future reference etc.
I've built an application with forms via Powershell over the last year which has evolved. I'm now wanting to make it a little quicker as the current search for installed software relies on me searching an .EXE file in the program folder and then checking the version properties. Works fine but it is a little slow when sivving through the program files.
Id stumbled across the registry for HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ which has helped me identify the software and installation location extremely quickly.
At the moment I have the following
$Keys = ("HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\*")

$InstalledSoftware = $Keys |
ForEach-Object { Get-ItemProperty $\_ } |
Where-Object { $\_.DisplayName -like 'Software 20\*' } |
Select-Object -Property DisplayName , InstallLocation

Which gives me the results below.
DisplayName            InstallLocation
-----------            ---------------
Software 2022          C:\Program Files\Software\Frederik\
Software 2021          C:\Program Files\Software\Frederik (2)\
Software 2024          C:\Program Files\Software\Frederik (3)\
Software 2023          C:\Program Files\Software Test\Frederik\

Sorry if this is a very crude explanation.
I don't know the correct terminology for this.
Thanks
I know I can use -Expand to extract the individual columns which I can then use. But if I just extract the Install Location as above I have no indication of what Installation Display Name is.
Basically what I'm looking at doing is getting this information from Both DisplayName & Install Location, If DisplayName version contains 2022 for instance then I'll set a variable to true. and the installation location to be as the above in another variable.
When I have tried to see if
$InstalledSoftware -contains 'Software 2022'
$SO-Location = 'C:\\Program Files\\Software\\Frederik'
$SO-Version = $true

At the moment I've been searching the Software Name and checking if it contains / eq XYZ as I don't need anything more advanced.

get-package and -like and single backslashes

After playing around with it for hours I finally found a method that worked. using the for each command.
ForEach($Software in $InstalledSoftware) {

    if ($Software.DisplayName -like 'SOFTWARE 2020*') {
        $Software20Installed = $true
        #$Software20Exe = Get-ChildItem -Path $Software.InstallLocation -recurse -include "SOFTWARE.exe" | % { $_.FullName } ###### SEARCHS
        $Software20Exe = Join-Path -Path $Software.InstallLocation -ChildPath 'SOFTWARE.exe'
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $SEARCHDELAY
    } else {}

I did try searching the for the EXE file type but it was still taking abit of time regardless of being in the correct directory to start with, and I knew the EXE files are all the same anyway, so I've just joined the install location path with the exe file which made it 10x quicker in the end.
